# An unexpected error has occurred! Ampscript Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have implemented a custom subscription center for one of my customer,  All works good and I am able to update the subscriptions also back in salesforce. But the issue is when the email is opened after some specific time(After a week or so), I get an error as attached in the screenshot. Please note that all works well if someone opens the subscription center (microsite) link immediately or in a week.

[image]

I guess the issue is with the data content of _subscriberkey.

Any ideas or suggestions are most welcome.

Many Thanks,

Kalpesh

Comment: Can you please confirm the data used to send the email which has the custom subscription centre is not deleted or purged after a week?

Comment: Hi Brad,

Yes the data used to send the email is not deleted or purged, It exist in the system as it is.

Comment: I'm not sure you should be seeing a <br/> in the error there - you should try editing your code in the HTML editor, removing that line break and then trying again.

Comment: Hi TCassa,
I am just adding this it as a label, the original value goes in third parameter

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of using raw personalization strings anywhere.  This is a good example for why you shouldn't do it.

I'm assuming you arrived at the page from Send Preview or directly without a Subscriber context.

I'd suggest replacing the line referenced in your screenshot with this:

```
var @sk
set @sk = AttributeValue("_Subscriberkey")
set @LOG = concat(@LOG, "<br/>_subscriberkey: ",@sk)
```

[**AttributeValue()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attributevalue.htm) handles this situation because it returns an empty string if the attribute doesn't exist. You can combine the use of AttributeValue() with the [**empty()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/empty.htm) function to proactively deal with personalization strings not existing.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Adam, 
I tried with the AttributeValue() but still facing following error.

An error occurred when attempting to evaluate an AttributeValue function call.  See inner exception for details.

ExactTarget.OMM.OMMException:  No custom object was found for the specified CustomObjectID

And I have properly send the email and this error I get when I click on the Microsite Landing page link after few days of email sent date